# Getting the correct polygon to show in image

Tags: java, polygon

really need your help now

I have some detection results.

[image: Image 1]

and i wish to show this result on this un-rotated image(please ignore the blue boxes)

[image: Image 2]

My logic for my algorithm is as follows

Given that the coordinates for the yellow box are with reference to the frame of reference(top left hand corner of Image 1), I am trying to find the coordinates for the yellow box with reference to the frame of reference of the top left hand corner of the inner image within Image 1.

So i used basic trigno(right-angled triangle at the bottom right corner of Image 1, to obtain the coordinates of the top left hand corner of the inner image and find the coordinates of the yellow box with reference to this point.

After which i use since i want to show the results on Image 2, i used the centre of the inner image as my rotation point and translate the coordinate of the yellow box with respect to this centre to the origin of the inner image(top left hand corner) and rotate using this matrix:

[image][x,y] where [x,y] are for my points

My resultant polygon on the image is this:

[image]

which my prof took a look at it and said it was wrong.

I have lost count how many times i went through the logic and implementation...it seems correct to me. Can any kind soul help me out here?

Here's part of my code:

//code for rotated image at 135 deg

```
 else if(nameForcompare.equals("135")){
       angle = 225;
       minPoint.set_y(catYmin); minPoint.set_x(catXmin); maxPoint.set_y(catYmax); maxPoint.set_x(catXmax);
       //Show detection results of rotated image
       g5.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
       g5.drawRect((int)minPoint.get_x(), (int)minPoint.get_y(), (int)(maxPoint.get_x()-minPoint.get_x()), (int)(maxPoint.get_y()-minPoint.get_y()));


       rotatedX = Double.parseDouble(originalWidth)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians((int)45));
         if(catXmin < rotatedX){
              o = imageHeight - catYmin;
              a = rotatedX - catXmin;
              theta = Math.atan(o/a);
              h = (o/Math.sin(theta));

           if(theta >= Math.toRadians((int)45)){   
              thetaZ = theta - Math.toRadians((int)45);

              oZ = h*Math.sin(thetaZ); //ycoordinate
              aZ = h*Math.cos(thetaZ); //xcoordinate

              varX = checkPointsBeforeRotationX(aZ);
              varY = checkPointsBeforeRotationY(oZ);
           }
           else{
              thetaZ = Math.toRadians((int)45) - theta;
              oZ = 0;                  //ycoordinate
              aZ = h*Math.cos(thetaZ); //xcoordinate

              varX = checkPointsBeforeRotationX(aZ);
              varY = checkPointsBeforeRotationY(oZ);                  

           }
              minPoint.set_x(varX);
              minPoint.set_y(varY);

         }
         else if(catXmin == rotatedX){
             theta = Math.toRadians((int)45);
             h = imageHeight - catYmin;

             o = h*Math.sin(theta); //ycoordinate
             a = h*Math.cos(theta); //xcoordinate

             varX = checkPointsBeforeRotationX(a);
             varY = checkPointsBeforeRotationY(o);                

             minPoint.set_y(varY);
             minPoint.set_x(varX);
         }
         else if(catXmin > rotatedX){
             a = imageHeight - catYmin;
             o = catXmin - rotatedX;
             theta = Math.atan(o/a);
             h = (o/Math.sin(theta));
        if(theta <= Math.toRadians((int)45)){     
             thetaZ = theta + Math.toRadians((int)45);

             oZ = h*Math.sin(thetaZ); //ycoordinate
             aZ = h*Math.cos(thetaZ); //xcoordinate

             varX = checkPointsBeforeRotationX(aZ);
             varY = checkPointsBeforeRotationY(oZ);
        }
        else{
             thetaZ = Math.toRadians((int)45) - theta;

             oZ = 0;                  //xcoordinate
             aZ = h*Math.cos(thetaZ); //ycoordinate 

             varX = checkPointsBeforeRotationX(oZ);
             varY = checkPointsBeforeRotationY(aZ);

        }
             minPoint.set_x(varX);
             minPoint.set_y(varY);

         }

         if(catXmax < rotatedX){
              o = imageHeight - catYmax;
              a = rotatedX - catXmax;
              theta = Math.atan(o/a);
              h = (o/Math.sin(theta));
         if(theta >= Math.toRadians((int)45)){        
              thetaZ = theta - Math.toRadians((int)45);

              oZ = h*Math.sin(thetaZ); //ycoordinate
              aZ = h*Math.cos(thetaZ); //xcoordinate

              varX = checkPointsBeforeRotationX(aZ);
              varY = checkPointsBeforeRotationY(oZ);
         }
         else{
              thetaZ = Math.toRadians((int)45) - theta;
              oZ = 0;                  //ycoordinate
              aZ = h*Math.cos(thetaZ); //xcoordinate

              varX = checkPointsBeforeRotationX(aZ);
              varY = checkPointsBeforeRotationY(oZ);  
         }
              maxPoint.set_x(varX);
              maxPoint.set_y(varY);

         }
         else if(catXmax == rotatedX){
             theta = Math.toRadians((int)45);
             h = imageHeight - catYmin;

             o = h*Math.sin(theta); //ycoordinate
             a = h*Math.cos(theta); //xcoordinate

             varX = checkPointsBeforeRotationX(a);
             varY = checkPointsBeforeRotationY(o); 

             maxPoint.set_y(varY);
             maxPoint.set_x(varX);

         }
         else if(catXmax > rotatedX){
             a = imageHeight - catYmax;
             o = catXmax - rotatedX;
             theta = Math.atan(o/a);
             h = (o/Math.sin(theta));
        if(theta <= Math.toRadians((int)45)){      
             thetaZ = theta + Math.toRadians((int)45);

             oZ = h*Math.sin(thetaZ); //ycoordinate
             aZ = h*Math.cos(thetaZ); //xcoordinate

             varX = checkPointsBeforeRotationX(aZ);
             varY = checkPointsBeforeRotationY(oZ);
        }
        else{
             thetaZ = Math.toRadians((int)45) - theta;

             oZ = 0;                  //xcoordinate
             aZ = h*Math.cos(thetaZ); //ycoordinate 

             varX = checkPointsBeforeRotationX(oZ);
             varY = checkPointsBeforeRotationY(aZ);
        }

             maxPoint.set_y(varX);
             maxPoint.set_x(varY);

         }

        getCorners();
        checkPointsAfterRotation(angle);
        checkCornerPointsAfterRotation(angle);

        g2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        g2.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);  
        Corners1 =0; Corners2 =0;








public static void rotate2(Point originForRotation, Point pointForRotation, Double angle){
double cos=Math.cos(angle);
double sin=Math.sin(angle);
double oX =originForRotation.get_x();
double oY =originForRotation.get_y(); 
double x=pointForRotation.get_x();
double y=pointForRotation.get_y(); 

x = x-oX;    y = y-oY; 


pointForRotation.set_x((cos*x-sin*y)+oX);
pointForRotation.set_y((sin*x+cos*y)+oY);    

pointForRotation.show();

}

public static void getCorners(){
    if((minPoint.get_x() > maxPoint.get_x()) && (minPoint.get_y() < maxPoint.get_y())){
      topleftPoint.set_x(maxPoint.get_x());  bottomrightPoint.set_x(minPoint.get_x());
      topleftPoint.set_y(minPoint.get_y());  bottomrightPoint.set_y(maxPoint.get_y());
      Corners1 = 1; 
    }
    else if((minPoint.get_x() > maxPoint.get_x()) && (minPoint.get_y() > maxPoint.get_y())){
      toprightPoint.set_x(minPoint.get_x());  bottomleftPoint.set_x(maxPoint.get_x());
      toprightPoint.set_y(maxPoint.get_y());  bottomleftPoint.set_y(minPoint.get_y());
      Corners2 = 1;
    }
    else if((minPoint.get_x() < maxPoint.get_x()) && (minPoint.get_y() < maxPoint.get_y())){
      toprightPoint.set_x(maxPoint.get_x());  bottomleftPoint.set_x(minPoint.get_x());
      toprightPoint.set_y(minPoint.get_y());  bottomleftPoint.set_y(maxPoint.get_y());
      Corners2 = 1;
    }
    else if((minPoint.get_x() < maxPoint.get_x()) && (minPoint.get_y() > maxPoint.get_y())){
      topleftPoint.set_x(minPoint.get_x());  bottomrightPoint.set_x(maxPoint.get_x());
      topleftPoint.set_y(maxPoint.get_y());  bottomrightPoint.set_y(minPoint.get_y());
      Corners1 = 1;
    }
}

public static Double checkPointsBeforeRotationX(Double pointX){
    if(pointX > (Double.parseDouble(originalWidth))){
      pointX = Double.parseDouble(originalWidth);
      }
    return pointX;
}

public static Double checkPointsBeforeRotationY( Double pointY){
    if(pointY > (Double.parseDouble(originalHeight))){
      pointY = Double.parseDouble(originalHeight);
    }
    return pointY;
}

public static void checkPointsAfterRotation(int angle){

        rotate2(origin, minPoint,  Math.toRadians((int)angle));    
        rotate2(origin, maxPoint,  Math.toRadians((int)angle)); 
         //check for out of bound points after rotation
            if(minPoint.get_y()< 0){
                minPoint.set_y(0);
            }
            else if(minPoint.get_y() > Double.parseDouble(originalHeight)){
                minPoint.set_y(Double.parseDouble(originalHeight));
            }
            if(minPoint.get_x()< 0){
                minPoint.set_x(0);
            }
            else if(minPoint.get_x() > Double.parseDouble(originalWidth)){
                minPoint.set_x(Double.parseDouble(originalWidth));
            }
            if(maxPoint.get_y()< 0){
                maxPoint.set_y(0);
            }
            else if(maxPoint.get_y() > Double.parseDouble(originalHeight)){
                maxPoint.set_y(Double.parseDouble(originalHeight));
            }
            if(maxPoint.get_x()< 0){
                maxPoint.set_x(0);
            }
            else if(maxPoint.get_x() > Double.parseDouble(originalWidth)){
                maxPoint.set_x(Double.parseDouble(originalWidth));
            }

        xPoints[0] = (int)minPoint.get_x(); 
        xPoints[2] = (int)maxPoint.get_x(); 

        yPoints[0] = (int)minPoint.get_y(); 
        yPoints[2] = (int)maxPoint.get_y(); 


}


 public static void checkCornerPointsAfterRotation(int angle){

    if(Corners1 == 0 && Corners2 == 1){

        rotate2(origin, toprightPoint,  Math.toRadians((int)angle));    
        rotate2(origin, bottomleftPoint,  Math.toRadians((int)angle));

        if(toprightPoint.get_y()< 0){
                toprightPoint.set_y(0);
            }
            else if(toprightPoint.get_y() > Double.parseDouble(originalHeight)){
                toprightPoint.set_y(Double.parseDouble(originalHeight));
            }
            if(toprightPoint.get_x()< 0){
                toprightPoint.set_x(0);
            }
            else if(toprightPoint.get_x() > Double.parseDouble(originalWidth)){
                toprightPoint.set_x(Double.parseDouble(originalWidth));
            }
            if(bottomleftPoint.get_y()< 0){
                bottomleftPoint.set_y(0);
            }
            else if(bottomleftPoint.get_y() > Double.parseDouble(originalHeight)){
                bottomleftPoint.set_y(Double.parseDouble(originalHeight));
            }
            if(bottomleftPoint.get_x()< 0){
                bottomleftPoint.set_x(0);
            }
            else if(bottomleftPoint.get_x() > Double.parseDouble(originalWidth)){
                bottomleftPoint.set_x(Double.parseDouble(originalWidth));
            }

            xPoints[1] = (int)toprightPoint.get_x(); xPoints[3] = (int)bottomleftPoint.get_x();
            yPoints[1] = (int)toprightPoint.get_y(); yPoints[3] = (int)bottomleftPoint.get_y();
        }
        else if(Corners1 == 1 && Corners2 == 0){


        rotate2(origin, topleftPoint,  Math.toRadians((int)angle));    
        rotate2(origin, bottomrightPoint,  Math.toRadians((int)angle));    

        if(topleftPoint.get_y()< 0){
                topleftPoint.set_y(0);
            }
            else if(topleftPoint.get_y() > Double.parseDouble(originalHeight)){
                topleftPoint.set_y(Double.parseDouble(originalHeight));
            }
            if(topleftPoint.get_x()< 0){
                topleftPoint.set_x(0);
            }
            else if(topleftPoint.get_x() > Double.parseDouble(originalWidth)){
                topleftPoint.set_x(Double.parseDouble(originalWidth));
            }
            if(bottomrightPoint.get_y()< 0){
                bottomrightPoint.set_y(0);
            }
            else if(bottomrightPoint.get_y() > Double.parseDouble(originalHeight)){
                bottomrightPoint.set_y(Double.parseDouble(originalHeight));
            }
            if(bottomrightPoint.get_x()< 0){
                bottomrightPoint.set_x(0);
            }
            else if(bottomrightPoint.get_x() > Double.parseDouble(originalWidth)){
                bottomrightPoint.set_x(Double.parseDouble(originalWidth));
            } 

            xPoints[1] = (int)topleftPoint.get_x(); xPoints[3] = (int)bottomrightPoint.get_x();
            yPoints[1] = (int)topleftPoint.get_y(); yPoints[3] = (int)bottomrightPoint.get_y();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's too much code to trace through in detail, but I'll assume that your code faithfully implements the math you described. I think the problem is that you are applying a pure rotation matrix. The transformation from rotated kitty to rotated yellow box is a composition of a translation and a rotation. You need to first translate kitty (and the yellow box) from (x,y) to (0,0) (so the rotated kitty image is position with kitty's top left at the top left of figure 1). Then you need to rotate everything clockwise by 135 degrees.

Using homogeneous coordinates and matrix multiplication will make your code a lot simpler.

Comment: In case you missed it, I explained that my algo actually uses both translation and rotation. However instead of what you suggested, i found the centre of my kitty image and translated it to the top left corner of figure 1 and have the coordinates of the yellow box around the centre translated as well. After which I rotated the image anticlockwise by 225 deg. Is this the same as you suggested?

Comment: @user1968818 - I was suggesting translating the top left corner of the kitty image to the top left of figure 1. I neglected to mention that the rotation should be about the top left corner of figure 1; I assumed that was the origin. If you translate the center, that would work if you then translated the center back to where it was supposed to be after the rotation. (Otherwise the kitty image would end up centered at the top left of figure 1.)